# Rails inserting javascript as a flash notice or message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm wondering if this is a good idea or not, either way I'd like you guys opinion on how to best achieve this sort of messaging popup system I have in my app.

Under some occasions I want to popup a lightbox for users when certain actions are triggered. I already have the lightbox working and opening when when my controller returns JS for a request.

Here is the senario, I want to check if a user has new `messages` when a new request is made, and if they do I want to show the messages in my lightbox when the new page is loaded.

Should I just put some JS at the bottom of my `<body>` and render it if the user has `messages`? Or should I use like `flash[:notice]` and have it render as JS or something... I'm a bit stuck you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use flash notices, this is not what they are for at all.  I would have something in the layout like this:

```
<% if (messages = current_user.new_messages).size > 0 %>
  <%= javascript_tag "display_messages(#{messages.collect(&:message_text).inspect})" %>
<% end %>
```

obviously here i'm guessing at your messages' methods but you get the idea.  .inspect will give it an array of strings, you could give it the message data as a json object or whatever.

Comment: Cool yah, I like this; this is probably the best route to go.